# Can I call the index of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, cell

So I have an image which I imported to python. The imread command basically gives me an array X,Y,Z where X and Y are the coordinates of the pixels and Z (which has four dimensions) gives me the RGB values at a given point (X,Y).

```
import matplotlib.image as img
import numpy as np



RawImg = img.imread('tek0000.bmp','RGB')
CrpImg = RawImg[14:208,12:256,:]

x_values = []
y_values = []

for row in CrpImg:
    for cell in row:
        print(np.nonzero)
        if (cell == [136,136,0,255]).all:
```

My goal is to analyze the exact points in the array where the RGB configuration is [136,136,0,255]. These points are greenish-yellow. I want to add the X and Y values to lists or arrays so I can plot them.

In order to achieve this, I iterate over every point X and Y (row and column) of the array, and analyze the Z values. What I need is the coordinate (X,Y) of the cell in the for loop.

Basically, if the color in the point (X,Y) of the image is yellow, add that point (X,Y) to the list.

Surprisingly I cannot find pretty much anything online for what I think, is a relatively simple thing. I realize that I can interate using the following: 
for i in range len(X axis) something like that, but I want to know if it is possible this way.

Comment: How can an RGB pixel have the value [136, 136, 0, 255]? The imported picture has a shape (h, w, 3), at least in my IDE.

Comment: Might be an RGBA, RGB + Alpha (transparency)

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure this is what you're looking for, but I think you want to get the index from inside the loop. The main ways to do this would be

1. loop using the index, e.g. `for i in range(0,255):` and then index into the array
2. iterate using `enumerate`, which returns an index as well as value in a collection
3. use the `index` method

I think the easiest option for you will be the `index` method.

```
for row in CrpImg:
    for cell in row:
        print(np.nonzero)
        if (cell == [136,136,0,255]).all:
            print(CrpImg.index(row), row.index(cell))
```

Note that this is going to give you the index inside your crop rather than the full image. You can either adjust (by adding 14 and 12), or you can iterate over the full image.

Comment: The index method is exactly what I want. However when I use your code I get the following error:

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: I assumed it was a list (often called array), didn't realize it was `np.array`.

Comment: Does the enumerate command give me the X and Y values? Let's say if A is true: give me X and Y. How would I implement this into my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) from the standard library, you get access to a tuple containing a count and your values. The count starts at 0 by default

```
for row in CrpImg
```

becomes

```
for num, row in enumerate(CrpImg):
    print(num)
```

Comment: And I assume I change the for loop for the columns as well then?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
indices = numpy.where(my_array == [136,136,0,255])
```

Comment: how would i implement this into the code? Do I put it into the for loop?

Comment: Check the documentation but this should return a n by 2 array containing the XY coordinates of each location where that color occurs. No loops necessary. I'm a little unclear on how your image is formatted. Might recommend loading it into opencv.